# How can I create a custom automatic status on Steam?

Tags: steam

I added a media player to Steam as a non-Steam game and changed its name to "watching movie". When I launch it from the games library it changes my status. But I want to make this change automatically everytime I play a movie. Is there anyway to do this?

P.S.: I don't want to change it to the movie's name that is currently playing. I just want to change it to "watching movie" when I start a video with that player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No** - this is not possible. Unless you launch an application or game from your Steam library, your Steam status will not update to reflect that the application (in this instance, your movie player) is running.

It is also not possible to create a custom status message on Steam. Adding your own games (or in your case, your media player) is [pretty much as far as the customisation of "what you're doing" goes](http://www.ctpftw.com/index.php?threads/how-to-add-custom-status-to-steam.130/). This is something that has been requested as a feature more than once in the past, for example [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2728007) on the Steam forums.

Comment: I guess you got me wrong. I dont want that "what you're doing" thingy. When you start a steam game it changes status to its name like "in-game a steam game" I just wondered its   adaptedness to a non-steam game

Comment: Yes - it will show the name of your non-Steam game, but it won't update in your instance where you're watching a movie and you want it to update with a custom status including the name of the movie. Steam will only show what you entered as the name of the non-Steam game.

Comment: seemingly I got the problem expressing myself. It is not about the name of movie that I played.

Comment: @emmett But he already gave you the answer in the first sentence: Unless you launch an application via you Steam libraray, your Steam status will not update to reflect that.

Comment: that was just added in his defence

Answer (score 3):

When you add a non-steam application/game to Steam, it will update under the "Now playing" heading, so if you renamed it to "Watching movie" when you load the app it will say "Now playing: Watching movie" or similar. Once you end the application, the status will just go back on "Online".

As for leaving the media player running, and having Steam automatically update your status depending on wether it is currently playing or not, I do not believe that is supported.